Issue displaying LocalStream in mirror or flipped mode in macOS Swift
i am working on macOS app and using webRTC
showing video on RTCMTLNSVideoView like this
func renderVideoCall() {
let renderer = RTCMTLNSVideoView(frame: self.view.frame)
renderer.wantsLayer = true
renderer.clipsToBounds = true
renderer.layer?.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0))
print("Renderer layer class: \(String(describing: renderer.layer?.className))")

// Add renderer to view
self.view.addSubview(renderer)
self.localVideoTrack = self.localStream?.videoTracks[0]
if let videoTrack = self.localVideoTrack {
  videoTrack.add(renderer)
  print("Video track successfully added to renderer.")
} else {
  print("Video track is nil.")
}
self.view.needsDisplay = true
}

What will be the solution for this ??
